# Is dark matter paramagnetic/diamagnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, astrophysics, astronomy, dark-matter

From my understanding, constrains on the interaction of dark matter with electromagnetic fields comes from the lack of scattering/absorption/emission of light.

But, do we know anything of its DC magnetic susceptibility?

Answer (score 2):

One would guess dark matter does not react to external magnetic fields at all.  If there were any sort of magnetic susceptibility it opens the door to it being observed and, thus, not dark.

Neutron stars, for example, are observable.

Of course, the real answer to your question is "maybe" because we simply cannot say very much about that which we cannot, by definition, observe.

Remember:  dark matter is matter whose existence we infer from gravitational effects on matter that we can observe via electromagnetism but that we cannot directly observe via electromagnetism.

Comment: "Of course, the real answer to your question is "maybe" because we simply cannot say very much about that which we cannot, by definition, observe." Not really, we know a whole lot about dark matter. For example, the answer could be "No, there is X evidence that it has no magnetic susceptibility to some degree", ie. if galaxies with the same characteristics but different DM content tend to have the same magnetic field strength in them.

Comment: "If there were any sort of magnetic susceptibility it opens the door to it being observed and, thus, not dark" - Yes.. and my question is, has DC magnetic susceptibility been observed (or hasn't it)? Which you don't really answer to be honest. Does DC susceptibility necessarily imply DM not being dark for light?

Comment: Gyro - I don't know.  Experimental physicists are kinda crafty people and I suspect they would have a way to detect magnetically susceptible, but otherwise invisible, matter.  But maybe they don't.  I also don't know much about the magnetic environment of a galaxy.  Your question deserves a better answer, but I gave you what I had.

Answer (score 1):

Dark matter does not interact with electromagnetism. If it did we would know if dark matter existed. It would be visible for the most part. It would interact more with matter that with just gravity. So no dark matter does not interact with matter. However dark matter can interact indirectly with matter and indirectly create electromagnetism using normal matter.

Comment: "Dark matter does not interact with electromagnetism." Ok, whats the evidence? "scattering/absorption/emission of light. (like I said)". Does this imply that it has no DC susceptiblity? Why?

Comment: Dark matter does none of those things. Dark matter does not reflect, absorb, or scatter light. If dark matter was doing those things the night sky would not be dark. This is because dark matter makes roughly 25% of the matter in the universe.

Comment: Again, like I said, "constrains on the interaction of dark matter with electromagnetic fields comes from the lack of scattering/absorption/emission of light.". But, "do we know anything of its DC magnetic susceptibility?". Just try to answer the question pls.

Comment: Of course it could interact with electromagnetic waves and we do not know it. As a matter of fact there is a theory of the dark electromagnetic waves that regular matter does not interact with.